# How to add data to the end of a CSV file (Java)

Tags: java, android, csv

I am developing an Android application that produces results and I am saving this results in a CSV file. After that I want to close the app, open it again, get other results and write them at the end of the same existing CSV file. Right now every time it ovverrides the previous results.
This is my class to save the results in a CSV file:

```
public class SaveCSV {
private File file;
private RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile;


public SaveCSV(){
    this.file = getPath("RisultatiTest.csv");
    try {
        this.randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void salvaRisultati (int[] array) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            s = s + array[i] + ",";
        }
        randomAccessFile.writeBytes(s);
        randomAccessFile.writeBytes("\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create File " + e);
    }
}

public static File getPath(String fileName){
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
}
```

}

Comment: `"rwd"` Please explain. Add an "a".

Comment: If you dont need random access you could use FileOutputStream in append mode.

Comment: What about `randomAccessFile.seek(randomAccessFile.length())` before writing?

Comment: Indeed. As explaind here. Simple google search. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Appendingdatatoexistingfile.htm